# Build error on gradle: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, gradle, build, minecraft, build-error

RouletteBlock.java Gradle Build Error

```
/root/pirate-roulette/src/main/java/com/nemosw/spigot/pirateroulette/RouletteBlock.java:158: error: cannot find symbol
        CustomEntityPacket.register(stand.getId()).sendTo(p);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method sendTo(Iterable<CAP#1>)
  location: interface Packet
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Player from capture of ? extends Player
/root/pirate-roulette/src/main/java/com/nemosw/spigot/pirateroulette/RouletteBlock.java:159: error: cannot find symbol
        CustomEntityPacket.scale(stand.getId(), 3.0F, 3.0F, 3.0F, 0).sendTo(p);
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   method sendTo(Iterable<CAP#1>)
  location: interface Packet
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Player from capture of ? extends Player
2 errors
```

While building this project, It causes error and I can't figure out what kind of error this is. Can anyone solve this problem for me?

[build.gradle](https://github.com/nemosrc/pirate-roulette/blob/master/build.gradle)

[RouletteBlock.java](https://github.com/nemosrc/pirate-roulette/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nemosw/spigot/pirateroulette/RouletteBlock.java)

[PirateRoulettePlugin.java](https://github.com/nemosrc/pirate-roulette/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nemosw/spigot/pirateroulette/PirateRoulettePlugin.java)

[mox-math/Vector.java](https://github.com/nemosrc/mox-math/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nemosw/mox/math/Vector.java)

[CustomEntityPacket.java](https://github.com/nemosource/plugin-CustomEntity/blob/master/src/nemo/plugin/customentity/CustomEntityPacket.java) - This is original Source so the package name is different from RouletteBlock.java

[nemosw/tap](https://github.com/nemosrc/tap/tree/1.2.19/core/src/main/java/com/nemosw/spigot/tap)

[bukkit](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fversion%2F1.12.2)

Answer (score 0):

The `Packet` returned by `CustomEntityPacket.register(...)` does not have a `sendTo(...)` method. See the [sourcecode of Packet](https://github.com/nemosource/lib-nemo-mc/blob/master/src/nemo/mc/packet/Packet.java#L28) to find the appropriate method to call (e.g. `send(Player)`).